# Ngnix still seeing welcome screen after configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, capistrano

I have set up and deployed an application using Capistrano, Nginx, Passenger and set up the server and ngnix config file, however, I'm still seeing the `Welcome to ngnix` welcome screen.

Here is what I have in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name IP;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/poladmin/poetry-out-loud-v2/current/public/;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

I have restarted Ngnix but I'm still not seeing the website.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Nginx is serving you the content from it's installation directory. It's usually `/usr/share/nginx` but you can confirm by running:

`nginx -V 2>&1 |  tr ' ' '\n' | grep prefix`

This will happen if it can't find a more suitable server from your configuration. Here's a few observations:

`server_name IP;`

This directive tells Nginx which host names to match in client requests in order to pass the request to this server. So requests to `http://ip` will be handled here, is that your intention?

Is your root directory really within someone's home directory structure? Fair enough...

You can lose the trailing slash from that directive, to make it:

```
root /home/poladmin/poetry-out-loud-v2/current/public;
```

but, but, what about the slash?

It lives in here:

```
location / {
    blah blah blah...
}
```

You currently have no location directives apart from `location = /50x.html` which contains `=` so is an exact match only. A request for any other URL doesn't have a matching location within this server block.

Answer (score 0):

try it with the folowing commands
first: `service nginx configtest`
to verify the Nginx functioning
second: `service nginx restart`